# How to show headers on a grid made with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I am trying to create a Markov Map, as described by Dias & Vermunt 2007 in Fig. 2. http://members.home.nl/jeroenvermunt/dias2006c.pdf

Here is the figure:

[image]

So far I have tried using grids for Ti*k*Z, which is working for gradient colouring, but I cannot seem to add the state names. I have also tried with tables, but this result does not look nice (very messy, different size of cells).

(I hope this is done correctly, as it is my first time here!)

Is there anyone who knows how to add header names and create a nice map?

Thanks a lot!

---

I cannot figure out to respond on a comment.. So I will do it this way. The matrix library of Ti*k*z works very well (I do get to see the results as posted in the comment), however when I extend it to a 22*22 matrix, an error appears:

Overfull \hbox - in nearly all paragraphs...

I tried changing the sizes size, minimum width and text width, but this did not help. Could you explain me what these measure mean and how to fix this? Thank You again!

---

I need several Markov maps next to each other, but the alignment does not work out as the bottom 2 maps are at different placings. Does someone know how to solve this?
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 1, $\pi_1 = 0.18$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=30mm, text width=28mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{   \&  AC  \&  CH  \&  DP  \&  HP  \&  IA  \&  LB  \&  LP  \&  NL  \&  SC  \&  show\_discount\_reminder    \&  show\_funnel\_campaign  \&  show\_recc  \&  show\_recp  \&  show\_upsell    \&  show\_wijnatlas     \&  WV  \&  XT  \\                                      
AC  \& |[fill=black!    2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  45  ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  37  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        

XT  \& |[fill=black!    8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  25  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 2, $\pi_2 = 0.16$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
%column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=43mm, text width=40mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{       AC  \&  CH  \&  DP  \&  HP  \&  IA  \&  LB  \&  LP  \&  NL  \&  SC  \&  show\_discount\_reminder    \&  show\_funnel\_campaign  \&  show\_recc  \&  show\_recp  \&  show\_upsell    \&  show\_wijnatlas     \&  WV  \&  XT  \\                                      
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  79  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        
     |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  14  ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  49  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\\                                                                    
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 3, $\pi_3 = 0.23$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
%row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=30mm, text width=28mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{AC \& |[fill=black!    2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  40  ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  40  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  7   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        

XT  \& |[fill=black!    4   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  18  ]|\& |[fill=black!  19  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  25  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  20  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  9   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 4, $\pi_4 = 0.13$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
%row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
%column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=43mm, text width=40mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{    |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  71  ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  21  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        

     |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  16  ]|\& |[fill=black!  11  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  19  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  40  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 5, $\pi_5 = 0.17$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
%row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=43mm, text width=40mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{AC \& |[fill=black!    1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  17  ]|\& |[fill=black!  4   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  76  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        

XT  \& |[fill=black!    4   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  9   ]|\& |[fill=black!  28  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  29  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  13  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  3   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  5   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Cluster 6, $\pi_6 = 0.12$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily, ampersand replacement=\&]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
%row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
%column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=43mm, text width=40mm, align=right}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{    |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  40  ]|\& |[fill=black!  6   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  18  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  33  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                        

     |[fill=black!  7   ]|\& |[fill=black!  1   ]|\& |[fill=black!  8   ]|\& |[fill=black!  29  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  19  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  10  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  15  ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  2   ]|\& |[fill=black!  7   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\& |[fill=black!  0   ]|\\                                    
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\label{TP_userS6}
\caption{Transition probabilities of user data (ADJ) using MMM}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, make complete small document begining with `\documnetclass{...}` and ending with  `\end{document}`. It seems that `matrix` library from TikZ can servew well in your problem.

Comment: Your last update is not related with the original one, so I think you should open a new question. When you do this, please follow Zarko's advice and provide a working code, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and be sure that the provided code, although reduced, provides results similar to what is shown in the corresponding figure. In this case, `tikz` code produces different result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `matrix`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\tiny]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
        row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
        column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=12mm, text width=10mm, align=left}},
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth
        ]
{
& frontpage & news & tech \\
frontpage & |[fill=red]| & |[fill=orange]| & \\
news & & |[fill=red!70!black]| & \\
tech & & |[fill=yellow]| & |[fill=red!70!black]| \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

The problem with the 22x22 matrix is not due to its size, but with the size of nodes is first column. In my previous example they were defined with

```
    column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=12mm, text width=10mm, align=left}},
```

with this size, they can fit `frontpage`, but not `show\_discount\_reminer`. If you declare column 1 nodes longer enough to cope with these long word, all messages about `overfull horizontal box` will desappear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[tb]
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\itshape]
\matrix (A) [nodes in empty cells,
matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, rotate=90, anchor=west, inner xsep=1mm}},
column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=43mm, text width=40mm, align=left}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth
]
{
&   AC &  ACRC  &   CH  &   DP    &   HP    &   IA    &   infl\_discount\_reminder &   infl\_funnel\_campaign    &   infl\_upsell  &   infl\_wijnatlas   &   LB    &   LP    &   NL    &   SC    &   show\_discount\_reminder  &   show\_funnel\_campaign    &   show\_recc    &   show\_recp &  show\_upsell  &   show\_wijnatlas   &   WV &  XT \\
AC & |[fill=black!    1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   39  ]|& |[fill=black!   6   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   43  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   8   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|\\
ACRC  & |[fill=black! 40  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   20  ]|& |[fill=black!   20  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   20  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|\\
CH    & |[fill=black! 0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   4   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   18  ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   30  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   22  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   22  ]|\\
DP    & |[fill=black! 6   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   17  ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   8   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   9   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   52  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|\\
HP    & |[fill=black! 2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   7   ]|& |[fill=black!   49  ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   18  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   5   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   13  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|\\
IA    & |[fill=black! 3   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   14  ]|& |[fill=black!   14  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   18  ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   25  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   19  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|\\
infl\_discount\_reminder  & |[fill=black! 2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   6   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   30  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   33  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   19  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|\\
infl\_funnel\_campaign    & |[fill=black! 0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   27  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   48  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   22  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|\\
infl\_upsell  & |[fill=black! 0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   64  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   36  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|\\
infl\_wijnatlas   & |[fill=black! 0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   64  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   27  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   9   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|\\
LB    & |[fill=black! 5   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   13  ]|& |[fill=black!   22  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   32  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   8   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   14  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|\\
LP    & |[fill=black! 6   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   8   ]|& |[fill=black!   4   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   36  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   8   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   18  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   15  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|\\
NL    & |[fill=black! 0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   5   ]|& |[fill=black!   81  ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|\\
SC    & |[fill=black! 0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   9   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|& |[fill=black!   4   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   47  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   23  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   6   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|\\
show\_discount\_reminder  & |[fill=black! 0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   82  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   7   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   5   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|\\
show\_funnel\_campaign    & |[fill=black! 0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   81  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   5   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   5   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|\\
show\_recc    & |[fill=black! 3   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   11  ]|& |[fill=black!   4   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   13  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   19  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   34  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   4   ]|& |[fill=black!   6   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   4   ]|\\
show\_recp & |[fill=black!    0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   50  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   50  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|\\
show\_upsell  & |[fill=black! 1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   4   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   6   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   4   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   45  ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|& |[fill=black!   32  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|\\
show\_wijnatlas   & |[fill=black! 10  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   12  ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   43  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   7   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   21  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|\\
WV & |[fill=black!    0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   9   ]|& |[fill=black!   33  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   19  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   24  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   10  ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|\\
XT & |[fill=black!    5   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   15  ]|& |[fill=black!   19  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   25  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   15  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   1   ]|& |[fill=black!   14  ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   3   ]|& |[fill=black!   2   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|& |[fill=black!   0   ]|\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Markov map aggregated data (S=1).}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @VivEUR You just need to change size of first column nodes. Look at updated answer. By the way, it's better to use `italics` text than  `$...$` because the space between letters is different.

Answer (score 2):

An approach similar to the one you proposed in your question is the following. I use two loops to label the columns and rows, then some `\fill` for selected cells and finally the grid. The grid is drawn as the last step, so that the lines of the grid cover the edges of the filled cells.

```
\documentclass [border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
    % Put column headers
    \foreach \header [count=\c] in {Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, consectetur, adipiscing, elit, Proin, vulputate, dignissim, odio, eu, euismod, sapien, sodales, eu, Curabitur, ipsum, nibh, dictum, eu} {
      \node[above] at (\c-0.5,22) {\rotatebox{90}{\small\sffamily\header}};
      }

    % Put row headers
    \foreach \header [count=\c] in {Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, consectetur, adipiscing, elit, Proin, vulputate, dignissim, odio, eu, euismod, sapien, sodales, eu, Curabitur, ipsum, nibh, dictum, eu} {
      \node[left] at (0,22-\c+0.5) {\small\sffamily\header};
      }

    % Fill some squares
    \fill[black!10] (0,21) rectangle +(1,1); % Use relative coordinates for the rectangle size
    \fill[black!30] (1,20) rectangle +(1,1); % Use relative coordinates for the rectangle size

    % Finally, the grid
    \draw[black, very thin] (0,0) grid (22,22);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]